# PHP Curl additional parameters for Woocommerce API

Tags: php, curl, woocommerce, php-curl, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm able to collect all orders using the default curl request:

`curl https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders -u consumer_key:consumer_secret`

But what I want to add a couple parameters and unsure how. I have tried adding it to the url, but with no luck:

`curl https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?status=completed&after=2023-06-01T00:00:00-00:00 -u consumer_key:consumer_secret`

I did try using `-d '{"status":"completed"}'`, but this seemed to create an order (even though I have not stipulated -X POST or PUT

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap the URL inside quotes. Execute the curl command like this:

```
curl "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?status=completed&after=2023-06-01T00:00:00-00:00" -u consumer_key:consumer_secret
```